# Create an image array in swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, image, swift, uiimageview

Hi I'm working with swift to create a game and I'm facing a problem.

I'm trying to have 20 images than I can simply control with a number (1,2,3,4,5...20)

I would have, for example, a for statement in which I would put a command to place the picture in the middle of the screen.

Let's clarify everything: it's buildup a game in which the user will need to tap a certain picture on the screen and, depending of the image, a certain action will occur.

I simply don't want to create 20 individual image view with 20 variable to define the type of the image. I would like to have an IbAction(for the button on top of the image) that will trigger a series of action depending on the image that has been touch and the type of picture that is in it.

I can build my game in simple Swift or use SpriteKit.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to:

1. Place all your images as the background image in buttons.
2. Give each one a unique tag in the attributes inspector
3. Connect all the buttons to the same IBAction
4. Use a switch statement to drive control flow

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBAction func imageSelected(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            println(sender.tag)
        case 2:
            println(sender.tag)
        default:
            break

        }
    }

}
```